# puppet not recognizing supported modules

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

When I try to install basic Windows modules (new to puppet) they are not recognized when I try to add their classes to a new group.

When I list the modules I can see them, when I checked the production module path it is in the right place, why can't I see them in the GUI?

Thanks..

```
[root@puppetmaster ~]# puppet module list <br>
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules<br>
├── badgerious-windows_env (v2.2.2)<br>
├── chocolatey-chocolatey (v1.2.1)<br>
├── puppet-download_file (v1.2.1)<br>
├── puppet-iis (v1.4.1)<br>
├── puppet-windowsfeature (v1.1.0)<br>
├── puppetlabs-acl (v1.1.2)<br>
├── puppetlabs-apache (v1.8.0)<br>
├── puppetlabs-concat (v1.2.5)<br>
├── puppetlabs-powershell (v1.0.6)<br>
├── puppetlabs-reboot (v1.2.1)<br>
├── puppetlabs-registry (v1.1.3)<br>
├── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.11.0)<br>
├── puppetlabs-windows (v2.1.1)<br>
└── puppetlabs-wsus_client (v1.0.1)<br>
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_accounts (v2.0.2-6-gd2f698c)<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_concat (v1.1.2-7-g77ec55b)<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_console_prune (v0.1.1-9-gfc256c0)<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_hocon (v2015.3.0-rc0)<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_inifile (v1.1.4-16-gcb39966)<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_java_ks (v1.2.4-37-g2d86015)<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_nginx (v2015.2.0-rc0)<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_postgresql (v3.4.4-35-g51cdb78)<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_puppet_authorization (v2015.3.0-rc1-31-g6d266e1)<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_puppetdbquery (v2015.3.0-rc1-1-gb278efd)<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_r10k (v2015.2.2-2-g21c67b9)<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_razor (v0.2.1-84-gbb045d2)<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_repo (v2015.3.0-rc2-39-g796afc6)<br>
├── puppetlabs-pe_staging (v0.3.3-24-g2d5dbb0)<br>
└── puppetlabs-puppet_enterprise (v2015.3.1-1-g8c41b9f)<br>
```

```
[root@puppetmaster ~]# puppet config print modulepath --section master --environment production
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules:/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the foreman GUI fetch installed modules, You need a foreman-proxy running with puppet.yml file enabled in it.

> Note: I hope you have a working foreman-proxy running with puppet.yml
>   file enabled. If it's not running, please enable puppet in
>   foreman-proxy and configure proxy settings in foreman GUI. That's
>   enough to make the classes visible.

I also pasted my puppet.conf file, just incase if you need.

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post
environment=production
reports=log, foreman

[master]
dns_alt_names = yourdomain.com
certname=yourdomain.com
external_nodes=/etc/puppet/node.rb
node_terminus=exec

[agent]
server=yourdomain.com
listen=true

[production]
modulepath=/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
```